# Get day (5) from timestamp (2014-03-05 08:36:00)

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I am trying to retrieve the day value as a number from a timestamp. I've been playing around with `date` and `getDate` functions, but to no success. Can anyone give me a hint please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo date('j', strtotime('2014-03-05 08:36:00'));
```

1. Uses `strtotime()` to turn the date into a Unix timestamp so I can pass it to `date()` for further formatting
2. [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns the day number without a leading zero as indicated by the `j` flag

Comment: OMG!. Strtotime. Did not know about that. Thank you very much. Will accept when I can.